# Коллайдеры проталкивают друг друга сквозь другой коллайдер Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть прямоугольный объект Scale.x = 1.0 Scale.y = 0.5 с `Rigidbody2D` и `Box Collider2D`, который при `OnCollisionEnter2D` с помощью `Fixed Joint2D` прикрепляется к всему, к чему прикоснется. Этот объект клонирую спаунером, и клоны падают на пол, который тоже имеет `Rigidbody2D` и `Box Collider2D`, но они при падении начинают проталкивать друг друга сквозь пол. Как мне можно это исправить? Скорость при падении маленькая, менял и массы их и все пробовал, `Interpolate` включено.

Comment: А как эти объекты с коллайдерами двигаются? Самостоятельно по физике? Или Вы в коде тоже как-то их передвигаете?

Comment: Самостоятельно по физике, они клонируются на небольшом расстоянии от пола

Comment: Толщину коллайдера пола увеличивать пробовали?

Comment: У меня получилось, что бы они не проваливались, при падении на пол, `Connected Rigid Body` был равен полу, но когда на него с верху падал еще один объект, то в `Connected Rigid Body` первого уже не факт, что был пол, но теперь когда их становится 3 в столбик, то их начинает сильно трясти

Comment: Да, при изменении толщины коллайдера пола ничего не изменялось, они просто входили в него